# Using currentTimeMillis() to compare concat and append

Tags: java, concatenation, stringbuilder

String conSingles = ""; //one to cong. single chars to
        String appendSingles = "";

```
    //Testing one char conc. and append
    long before = System.currentTimeMillis(); //static method so no new
    for(int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <70000; j++) {
            conSingles += "j";
        }
        conSingles=""; //Clear string
    }
    long after = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long before2 = System.currentTimeMillis(); //static method so no new
    for(int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
        StringBuilder appSingles = new StringBuilder(); //one to append single chars to
        for (int j = 0; j < 75000000; j++) {
           appSingles.append("j");
        }
       appendSingles = appSingles.toString();
        appendSingles = "";
    }
    long after2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long total = (after-before)/10;
    long total2 = (after2-before2)/10;
```

I am comparing how many one char strings I can put together in 1000 msec with String concat vs StringBuilder append. I am close to 1000 msec when I run the loop once, but when I do it ten times, for average, I always get around 3-400 msec in average per round. What is it in my method that makes round of one so slow compared to 10 rounds?

Comment: First, if you are calculating intervals of time, use `System.nanoTime()`.  System.currentTimeMillis() is unreliable for interval timing.

Comment: [This article](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-benchmarking.html) goes into some detail about why JVM performance might vary over time.  Basically Java execution isn't static, and the optimizer might change how your code runs while the code is running.  To control this for benchmarking we generally have to add a warm-up time for the JVM to give the optimizer a chance to finish its work, and so meaningful timing tests can be taken.